# Permission issues while executing stored procedures in teradata

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata

I have created a procedure in different database than the user used to create it, 
The user I used to create the procedure is like 'vbhas' and the database it is created is like 'IFSRD', when I login as 'vbhas' and try to execute the proc it gives the error, could you please let me know how to modify the  execute access so that I will be able to execute this procedure successfully?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the SECURITY option. Depending on the SQL in the SP and your needs this might be SECURITY CREATOR|OWNER|INVOKER instead of the default DEFINER.

You should [read the manuals](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/I5Vi6UNnylkj3PsoHlLHVQ/HjSBm~nzRvO_ymyThIk4pg) for details

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dnoeth...

Got to know that Teradata gives permissions at database level, so now I created the procedure in the database which has execute permissions to all objects.